# How to save downloaded file to another server

Tags: java, scala

Mostly I use `new URL(downURL) #> new File("D:/MyFiles")!!` to download a file from a given downloading url of a file and it saves the file to `D:/MyFiles` on my computer.But instead of saving locally I want this file to be stored on my server i.e `192.168.1.22` while downloading.So how can I specify IP address in the line of code above so file gets saved directly to a particular server.

Comment: `new FileOutputStream("\\\\192.168.1.22\\SHARE\\download.txt")` ?

Comment: @Jan not working its string it locally with name `\\\\192.168.1.22\\SHARE\\download.txt`, also I am using linux

Comment: Code was for writing to windows share... Please elaborate (edit your question) to show: What do you have (setup, code, etc), what have you tried so far?

Comment: this is my entire code simple 3 lines of code

Comment: `val downURL = "http://192.168.1.125:8081/factory/lib-test/supai-api_0.8.-LV-SNAPSHOT_all.deb"`

Comment: `new URL(downURL) #> new FileOutputStream("/192.168.1.22/home/administrator/Desktop/abc.deb") !!`

Comment: I experimented with it a lot trying tried to give path in different way but not working

Comment: Once more: Edit your question. Otherwise others (not reading all comments) will not be any wiser. So far I've gathered this: You have some process running on a windows box (?) and you want to access network resource from there and then store it on a server path. -> Have you considered using shares? So you would store locally... but on a network share hosted on the server? Or is the concept of downloading unclear?

Comment: its so simple i am running linux and server is also running linux so I download a file using above code and simply instead of storing it locally want to store it on my server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96560/discussion-between-jan-and-aamir).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need an open port on your server where you can send data to,maybe http(s),(s)ftp or something else so you can transmit data to your server.
If you use http you can use `java.net.HttpURLConnection` to connect to your server and open an OutputStream and write data to it.

Here is an example(I haven't tested it):

```
public void writeDataToServer()
{
    URL downloadURL=new URL("example.com/example.pdf");
    URL serverIP=new URL("192.168.0.1");
    URLConnection downloadConnection=downloadURL.openConnection();
    URLConnection serverConnection=serverIP.openConnection();
    InputStream downloadStream=downloadConnection.getInputStream();
    OutputStream serverStream=serverConnection.getOutputStream();
    while((int r=downloadStream.read())!=-1)
    {
        serverStream.write(r);
    }
    downloadStream.close();
    serverStream.close();
}
```

You will need to catch some exceptions here and specify which HTTP Method you would like to use before opening a stream to your server.

Answer (score 1):

As clarified in chat: Storing what you download into a `File` will only be possible if you make the server's filesystem accesible to the client - by ways of NFS, Samba or other techniques.